# Difference in linked lists between c and java

Tags: java, c, linked-list, nodes

In java i cant add a node to a linked list when i visit null for example

```
void add(int val,node k){
    while(k!=null)
    k=k.right;
    k=new node(val,null);
}
```

Where as in C

```
void add(ll* ll1,int val){
    node* neu=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    neu->val=val;
    neu->right=NULL;
    if(ll1->head==NULL){
        ll1->head=neu;
        return;
    }
    node** curr=&(ll1->head);
    while(*curr){
        curr=&((*curr)->right);
    }

    (*curr)=neu;
}
```

I can add a node when i visit NULL. Can someone please explain me the difference ?Why does it work like this ?

Im sorry if my question is explained badly.(you can ask in comments to understand better)

Comment: Because Java tries to be a "safe" language, and C doesn't pretend to be one. C is therefore more powerful when it comes to certain applications of it.

Comment: There's no "visiting NULL" in your C code example - it's working the same way as the Java, by adding the node at the end of the list.

Comment: Does your C code actually work? I thought it would work the same way as in Java..

Comment: The java code doesnt work. The C one does. for the java code to work i have to stop before i go right the while loop should be while(k.right!=null)

Comment: Downvotes come for lack of prior research, unclear input and asking about things that could be found in the first chapter of any reasonable book on the subject. Just to name some of the reasons that result in downvotes here.

Comment: I can add the whole C code if anyone wishes to see

Comment: In C you are using a pointer to a pointer. Such a thing does not exist in Java.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you have a well defined location in memory where you encounter this null. Then you replace that null value with your new node.

In Java, you are trying to put a new node in the middle of nowhere. This null is not linked to anything anymore. Sure, you know it came from k.right, but you at that point of `k = new` you only have the null value, not its address. Unlike in C. So, there is no way to put new node anywhere and you get error.

As you figured out yourself, simply use the `k.right!=null` check. This is essentially what the C code is doing too, just hidden behind another layer of pointers.

Comment: Does the java version also not have any means of passing back the first node if it's created?

Comment: @ChrisTurner You mean in case this node you are passing to is not initialized, can you create and return it?
With the function as written, nope - if you give this function node=null, there is no way it could create something and return. 

But for example if you passed it "linkedListStart", which is a structure that contains a node (that might be null), then you could put the first node to the list. Which is what the C code is actually doing - there is a ll1 which has "head" = first node. And if that first node is null, put the freshly created one there. If ll1 itself is null, it crashes.